# Having trouble finding minimum time value of vector

Tags: c++

Basically I'm trying to create a function that finds the minimum value among a vector of time values. It does this by creating a clone vector and deleting everything except the minimum value. This code uses a helper function "isSmaller" to reach the result, but I have verified that this other function works fine.

```
tm findMin(vector<tm> myvector) {
    vector<tm> tempvector = myvector;
    for (vector<tm>::iterator it = tempvector.begin();
    it!=tempvector.end(); ++it) {
        if (isSmaller(*it, *it++) == true) {
            tempvector.erase(it);
        } else {
            tempvector.erase(it++);
        }
        it = tempvector.begin();
    }
    return tempvector.front();
}
```

When testing this, these are the values placed into the vector (in order).

```
Fri Dec 31 00:00:00 1999
Tue Dec 11 11:11:11 1900
Mon Jun  5 05:05:05 1950
Mon Apr  3 03:03:03 1933
Fri Dec 31 00:00:00 1999
```

The code will iterate three times. This is what the "it" value shows each time:

```
it start: Fri Dec 31 00:00:00 1999
isSmaller = true;
it end: Tue Dec 11 11:11:11 1900

it start: Mon Jun  5 05:05:05 1950
isSmaller = true;
it end: Tue Dec 11 11:11:11 1900

it before: Mon Apr  3 03:03:03 1933
isSmaller = false;
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I'm guessing that deleting the it value causes problems during the iteration, but how would I go about fixing this?

Comment: You fix it by not making a temporary copy of anything, and then not erasing anything in the first place. Finding a minimum value of something in the vector never requires anything of this sort. A simple `for` loop, with a comparison inside, and nothing else, is always sufficient, no matter how convoluted the definition of "smaller" is.

Comment: " It does this by creating a clone vector and deleting everything except the minimum value" - why would you think that is a good way of doing what you want?

Comment: `std::min_element(time_vector.begin(), time_vector.end(), [&](time_type& v1, time_type& v2) { return /* true if v1 < v2, false otherwise*/;});` -- Why not do something like that, instead of the convoluted code you have now?  What you're doing is what [std::min_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) is designed to do.

Comment: @OP This sounds like the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), but in your defense, you specified "X" and "Y".  But you're posting a "Y"-like solution to the "X" problem.

Comment: Because when I tried std::min_element, it didn't work. It's not working with this use of it either unfortunately.

Comment: "Comparison and nothing else"? How? Surely you'd have to at least swap them for some kind of insertion sort or something.

Comment: @Monzaku Whet do you mean `std::min_element` "didn't work"?  If anything you didn't post your `isSmaller` implementation, as that is what is missing from your post.  If you read the documentation to `min_element`, you see what the requirements are -- obviously `isSmaller` must be violating them.

Comment: @Monzaku You are comparing two `tm` objects now in `isSmaller`.  That is what `std::min_element` predicate is requiring, so nothing is stopping you from discovering how to provide those 2 arguments to the `min_element` predicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but how would I go about fixing this?

You asked, so here is an answer.

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
tm findMin(const vector<tm>& myvector) 
{
   return *std::min_element(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), 
                           [&](tm& v1, tm& v2) { return isSmaller(v1, v2); });
}
```

The assumption is that `isSmaller` returns `true` if the first parameter is actually less than the second parameter, `false` otherwise (make sure that this is how that function works).

Given that, there is no need to erase elements, copy to temporary vectors, etc.  All that is needed is to call [std::min_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) with a (working) predicate that returns `true` if `v1 < v2`, and `false` otherwise.

Edit:
Your `isSmaller` function needs to be `const` correct for the implementation shown.  In addition, that requires the arguments to the lambda to be also `const`, (which were not before):

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
bool isSmaller(const tm& v1, const tm& v2)
{
   return // true or false;
}

tm findMin(const vector<tm>& myvector) 
{
   return *std::min_element(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), 
                           [&](const tm& v1, const tm& v2) { return isSmaller(v1, v2); });
}
```

Your functions should have been made (or should have been from the start) `const` correct.  You are not changing the original passed-in vector, so it should have been a `const` reference.  If `isSmaller` doesn't change neither of the two arguments, they also should be `const` references.

Here is a [Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e3702326d883e66), showing comparing just the seconds in the date.  This should give you an idea of how to implement the proper `isSmaller` function.